# How can I commit changes that I've made in node_modules back to git?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

Sometimes it's easier to maintain a fork of a node package for your module, I'd like to be able to edit a module that's in `node_modues` that I've installed via `npm install githubaccount/myrepo.git`.

Currently any changed that I made to a file I have to copy back to the repo. This is tedious.

How can I edit modules in npm and have them tracked by Git?

Python's `pip` has an option where you can define an 'egg' which symlinks a clone of the repo to the site_packages folder. I know it's a different system, but I've found it really quite useful in the past.

Comment: Clone your forked repository, edit it separately from your project. Push it back to git. And then run *npm install* from your project where you use your forked repo.

Comment: That's what I do already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `npm link` command to do this. Here's how to use that. Let's assume that your npm module is located in `~/npm-module` and your project using the npm module is in `~/my-project`.

```
cd ~

# First clone the npm module
git clone https://..../npm-module.git

# Go into the module's directory:
cd npm-module

# Link the module
npm link

# CD into the project using the npm module
cd ../my-project

# Link the module
npm link npm-module
```

The first call to `npm link` will create a link in npm's cache directory pointing to your local clone of the npm-module. The second call will link it into the project that's using the module (into the `node_modules` folder).

If you take a look at your project's `node_modules` folder, you will see that it now contains a symbolic link to the `npm-module`'s sources. Any changes you make in that folder will also be in the cloned project. You can commit changes there and push them back to your remote.

This is similar to what you do with Python's `egg` feature.

Here's the [npm link documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was having trouble understanding what the npm link actually did, the fact that it caches the module fills in the missing part of the puzzle.